# Hybris: Mark products with no super-category as inactive

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We are performing catalog clean up task and require all products which have no super-category to be marked as inactive. Such products can be seen lying directly under the catalog root in PCM and not under any super-category.

I want to get the list of all such products and via impex I can update the approvalStatus of all such products as 'check', so that they are no longer visible to user at storefront.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Get your target products**

The idea is to extract all products from 'YOUR_CATALOG_ID' except (not in) all the products that have at least one category.
You could use this flexible search:

```
select {p.pk}
from { Product as p join CatalogVersion as cv on {p.catalogversion}={cv.pk}
  join Catalog as catalog on {cv.catalog}={catalog.pk} }
where {catalog.id}='YOUR_CATALOG_ID'
and {cv.version}='Staged'
and {p.pk} not in ({{
  select {p.pk}
  from {Product as p join CategoryProductRelation as pc on {p.pk}={pc.target}
    join Category as c on {pc.source}={c.pk} 
    join CatalogVersion as cv on {p.catalogversion}={cv.pk}
    join catalog as catalog on {cv.catalog}={catalog.pk}}
  where {catalog.id}='YOUR_CATALOG_ID'
  and {cv.version}='Staged'
}})
```

You should replace "Product" with your custom Product Type if your data model has been customized.

**Update products approvalStatus**

As second step you could create an impex in order to change the approvalStatus:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];approvalstatus(code);
;target_product_pk;check;
```